# How to delete a selected number of row after a find

Tags: batch-file

I would like to delete a selected number of row after a row that I will find.
Currently I only find the row and delete this one. 
I would like to delete 2 row up and down after my line.

```
 @echo off
    type file.txt | find /v "toto" | find /v "tata" > outputfile.txt
```

and my file look like that :

```
<KeyValuePairs>
 <ObjectID></ObjectID>
 <Key>toto</Key>
 <Value />
</KeyValuePairs>
```

So to explain, my script find the line "key" and I want to delete all my KeyValuePairs.

Actually I'm trying to count all my row in my file

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('type file.txt') do (
    set /a nb+=1
    )
echo %nb%
```

but it let my "nb" to 0. 
Do you know where the problem is? 
thanks for your help !

Comment: Your question, is off topic, _this isn't a script request service_, and unclear. Do you want to remove every line including and between `<KeyValuePairs>` and `</KeyValuePairs>`? Or perhaps, any line containing the string `toto` and all lines above and below it up to and including the string `KeyValuePairs>`? Or do you really want to remove any line containing the string `toto` and exactly two lines above and below it? Please clarify your requirements, and [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60650100/edit) to include the code you would like us to assist you with.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, what I want is to remove every line including and between <KeyValuePairs> and </KeyValuePairs> WHERE the key is equal to "toto" or "tata". My code where I need you to help me is already on it, it is the "type file.txt | find /v "toto" | find /v "tata" > outputfile.txt".
Actually I find and remove the line with the key toto but not all the parents of this tag.

Comment: Actually my code make a copy of my file in another file removing the line with "toto" and "tata". I don't want you to make a script for me, i just don't understand how to delete a selected number of row after a selected line. I don't want you to script for me but to explain me how to tell that I want to delete 2 row after the row that I've already deleted in my new file. Or just a ressource that I could check to help me ^^'

Comment: You need to search, read, learn, and try, you cannot expect us to tutor you. The problem with tutoring you is that we essentially have to write your code for you, then step through it in stages of varying sizes, _(dependent upon your level of understanding)_, it still requires us to write your script for you as part of the process. Questions requesting books, resources etc. are off topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: thanks for your advice, I've upgraded my post and will continue thx

Comment: `for /f "delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /n "toto" file.txt') do echo %%a` might get you started.

Comment: It looks as though your file is either an XML document, or an XML fragment. As such, you should be using XSLT or XQuery (or some other tool that fully understands XML syntax). Manipulating the file through some other means runs the risk of corrupting the result.

Comment: Hello dbenham, it is a rtsx file, I don't change the extension of my file when I treat it so I don't think that there will be any risk of corrupting the result no ?
Thanks Stephan your writing work and am actually trying to solve my problem with it ! many thanks,

Comment: Your problem is not a trivial one. You first need to find _the numbers_ of the lines where your search terms appear and store them somewhere. Then, in a _second pass_ through file lines, duplicate the lines _excepting_ when the line number is between the interval you want to omit (lineFound-2 thru lineFound+2). After that you must continue the previous procedure using _the next_ lineFound...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a pure batch implementation of your strategy. The code is heavily commented to explain how it works. The code should perform well as far as batch scripts go. Slight variations in the source file format can easily break the code, but that is an inherent risk of your design.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "input=file.txt"
set "output=output.txt"
set "tempFile=find.txt"

:: Prepare find.txt containing all the line numbers that should be excluded.
:: Each line consists of a line number followed by a colon.
:: The findstr lists the lines that contain one of the search terms, with the
:: line number followed by colon as a prefix.
:: The FOR /F parses the results to get the line numbers.
:: The DO clause computes the begin and end values and iterates all values
:: in between so can echo to the find.txt file.
::
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
>"%tempFile%" (
  for /f "delims=:" %%N in ('findstr /n "\<toto\> \<tata\>" "%input%"') do (
    set /a "beg=%%N-2, end=%%N+2"
    for /l %%N in (!beg! 1 !end!) do echo %%N:
  )
)
endlocal

:: The first FINDSTR prefixes each line with the line number followed by a colon.
:: The second FINDSTR excludes all the line numbers specified in find.txt.
:: The FOR /F parses the result and strips the line number prefix so can output
:: the final result.
::
>"%output%" (
  for /f "delims=: tokens=1*" %%A in (
    'findstr /n "^" "%input%" ^| findstr /vbig:"%tempFile%"'
  ) do @echo(%%B
)
del "%tempFile%"
```

Below is a one liner using a regular expression text processing utility called [JREPL.BAT](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044). This should be more reliable, as it only recognizes tata or toto within a `<Key>` element. It also does not care about where newlines appear.

```
jrepl "[\s\S]*<Key>(toto|tata)</Key>[\s\S]*" "" /m /p "<KeyValuePairs>[\s\S]*?</KeyValuePairs>\r?\n?" /f test.txt /o output.txt
```

Since JREPL itself is a batch script, you would need to use `CALL JREPL` if you put the command within a batch script.